# How do I perform a release upgrade on a server running Landscape?

Tags: upgrade, openstack, lts, landscape

I'm attempting to perform a release upgrade from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS, on my server running Landscape.

The upgrade is blocked due to

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
This was likely caused by:
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
```

According to the upgrade log, the unofficial software is the landscape server (if I'm interpreting "Foreign" correctly):

```
2020-11-18 19:17:24,416 DEBUG Foreign: landscape-client landscape-common landscape-hashids landscape-server landscape-se
rver-quickstart libjs-yui3-common libjs-yui3-full libjs-yui3-min python-convoy python-pyjwkest python-pyoidc python-stor
m python-stripe python-talisker python-txamqp python-txaws python-txjuju python-txlongpoll
```

I also see later in the log that

```
2020-11-18 19:17:56,869 DEBUG blacklist expr '^postgresql-.*[0-9][0-9].*' matches 'postgresql-10-debversion'
2020-11-18 19:17:56,869 DEBUG The package 'postgresql-10-debversion' is marked for removal but it's in the removal black
list
2020-11-18 19:17:56,884 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'The package 'postgresql-10-debversion' is marked for removal but it
is in the removal blacklist.'
2020-11-18 19:17:56,884 DEBUG abort called
```

so it's possible the "unofficial software" warning is a red herring.

Has anyone successfully done a release upgrade on a server running Landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll save future readers the trouble.

https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/onprem

```
Landscape On-Premises, is the standalone version of Landscape that you can install on your own network.

Each major Landscape version is supported for a period of one year after release. Here are the current supported releases:

MAJOR VERSION   RELEASE DATE    SUPPORTED UNTIL   VERSION OF UBUNTU
19.10           2019-Oct        2021-Oct          18.04 LTS
```

I did try to back up the database and just remove the offending postgres package, which worked, or ... at least, I could get further in the upgrade process. But during the upgrade the landscape packages were also removed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Landscape 19.10 only works on 18.04 for now, maybe on the next release we we'll have support for 20.04 as well.